# PDF Loads in Acrobat but Not in Browser

Tags: html, pdf

So, I create a pdf in Photoshop and aside from it being immense, it won't open in a browser.  When I download with the HTML5 "download" attribute, the file downloads correctly, but if I double click in Chrome, I get a blank screen.  If I go to the file manager and double click the pdf, it opens in Acrobat correctly.

Also, how do I decrease the file size?  The PDF I have is almost 100MB and it's only 10 pages.

Comment: Is there a way for me to check to check out the pdf somewhere online?

Comment: http://www.vegasletter.com/preview

Comment: Acrobat Reader is the canonically "correct" PDF reader. If it works in there but not elsewhere, the problem lies in *that* software. Your PDF may contain stuff that isn't supported by Chrome, or it may just be too large.

Answer (score 0):

In photoshop (CC/CS6) go to file -> save as -> select PDF

This will open up a settings screen. In the general tab make sure "Preserve photoshop editing capabilities is NOT checked" and "Optimize for Fast Web Preview " IS checked [image: Screenshot of the settings screen (make sure you uncheck first option)] This will make sure your pdf is tiny and optimized for fast web preview in Chrome.

Comment: FWIW, optimizing for fast web view has not much effect for images, because images are saved as single objects anyway. However, preserve Photoshop editing capabilities do have a big effect on the size, because this option essentially embeds the .psd file in the PDF. Besides these two settings, a considerable effect on the resulting file size is in the Compression settings (and, if JPEG is used, its qualitiy settings).